# How to access an element of an std::array given its pointer in C++

Tags: c++, function, pointers, compiler-errors, stdarray

I'm trying to access an element of an `std::array` given its pointer in C++. Here's some code that illustrates my problem:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>

void func(std::array<int, 4> *);

int main()
{
    std::array<int, 4> arr = {1, 0, 5, 0};
    func(&arr);
}

void func(std::array<int, 4> *elements)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i = i + 1)
    {
        std::cout << *elements[i] << std::endl;
    }
}
```

I would expect this to print every element of the `std::array` on a new line. However, it doesn't even get past compiling:

```
main.cpp: In function ‘void func(std::array<int, 4ul>*)’:
main.cpp:16:22: error: no match for ‘operator*’ (operand type is ‘std::array<int, 4ul>’)
         std::cout << *elements[i] << std::endl;
```

What's going on here?
Thanks!

Comment: The syntax is awkward, a good reason to pass the array with a & reference instead of a * pointer.  You don't like a nullptr anyway.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use

```
std::cout << (*elements)[i] << std::endl;
```

instead. Otherwise `operator[]` is applied first, as it has higher precedence, see http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence.

So you first need to dereference the pointer to get access to the first pointee, which is an `array`, then subsequently access the array with `operator[]`. Otherwise your code is parsed by the compiler as `*(elements[i])`, so first you get the `i`-th array (which of course is non-existent unless `i==0`), then you try to dereference it, hence the compile error.

Tip: If you're worried about copies, pass the array by `const` reference instead

```
void func(const std::array<int, 4>& elements)
```

Then your syntax inside the function will be "natural", i.e. `elements[i]` will simply denote the `i`-th element of the array reference `elements`. You'll also pass the array simply as `func(arr);`.

Answer (score 6):

**@vsoftco's answer is quite correct.**

I would just like to add that it is more idiomatic in `C++` to pass large objects by *reference*, rather than *pointer*:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>

// declare parameter as a reference
void func(std::array<int, 4>&);

int main()
{
    std::array<int, 4> arr = {1, 0, 5, 0};
    func(arr); // no need to take address
}

void func(std::array<int, 4>& elements)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i = i + 1)
    {
        // just use as normal
        std::cout << elements[i] << std::endl;
    }
}
```

If the function will not modify the array then *const reference* would be more appropriate:

```
void func(const std::array<int, 4>& elements)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i = i + 1)
    {
        // just use as normal
        std::cout << elements[i] << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

**Alternate answer**

While the other answers are correct too, I'd like to suggest another variant because there are cases where rewriting the code to use references is not always possible:

```
std::cout << elements->at(i) << std::endl;
```

This is a variant that avoids the pointer-de-referencing `(*element)` but uses the `std::array::operator->`. It may also be simpler to read.

Comment: Small comment: [`std::array::at()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array/at) does bound checking, which is OK (and recommended) when debugging the code, but sometime one may not want it (e.g. in high performance code where bound checking will burn CPU cycles).

Comment: @vsoftco, you're correct. The `at()` function does bounds checking. However, bounds-checking is perhaps the fastest on std::array among all the containers. So, I would not limit its use only to debug code.